# Using libGLE to extrude profile with holes

Tags: opengl

I'm looking for a way of extruding a profile with holes. I found the 'GLE Tubing and Extrusion Fact Sheet' but I don't know how to extrude holes?

Wanting to extrude an 'O', do you extrude two 'U' and then flip one of them? Example would be nice. I don't need GTS or openCASCADE for this simple task.

Also, is libGLE public domain code? Very little documentation exists.

Comment: If it doesn't say, then it's best to assume it's not public domain.

Comment: Download the source code. License and example code can be found there.

Comment: It is public domain, so yes, lets drop that. What about the main question?

Comment: The latest update to this library was 10 years ago, so it might be very outdated. If you want to give it a go.. you can still find example source code with the source files.